# Why is my JSON response being returned surrounded with square brackets[]?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why my JSON response is being surrounded with square brackets. I'm using ASP.NET web API and Angular. I'm thinking that this is the reason that my Angular code is not printing to the HTML.

```
namespace GeekQuiz.Controllers
{
    public class TrialController : ApiController
    {
        private TriviaContext db = new TriviaContext();

        // GET api/trial
        public IQueryable<TriviaQuestion> GetTriviaQuestions()
        {
            return db.TriviaQuestions;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is from my `TrialController` which I'm making a get call from Angular.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('questCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/api/trial").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.options = data.options;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.title = "Oops... something went wrong";
        $scope.working = false;
    });
});
```

Here is my view page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="questCtrl">

    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="option in options">
            <td>{{ option.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ option.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ option.questionId }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

<address>
    One Microsoft Way<br />
    Redmond, WA 98052-6399<br />
    <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr>
    425.555.0100
</address>

<address>
    <strong>Support:</strong>   <a href="mailto:Support@example.com">Support@example.com</a><br />
    <strong>Marketing:</strong> <a href="mailto:Marketing@example.com">Marketing@example.com</a>
</address>
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/angular.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/quest-controller.js")
}
```

I'm playing around with ASP.NET and trying to learn how to build a restful application with Angular and .NET. I'm using this tutorial [angular with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-%28spa%29-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) and a Lynda.com course on ASP.NET.

Here is my JSON response. How do I get ride of the square brackets? I don't know why they are there.

```
[
  {
    "options":[
      {"id":1,"title":"2000","questionId":1},
      {"id":2,"title":"2001","questionId":1},
      {"id":3,"title":"2002","questionId":1},
      {"id":4,"title":"2003","questionId":1}],
    "id":1,
    "title":"When was .NET first released?"
  },
  {
    "options":[
      {"id":5,"title":"Contoso Ltd.","questionId":2},
      {"id":175,"title":"System.DateTime","questionId":44},
      {"id":176,"title":"System.Float","questionId":44}
    ],
    "id":44,
    "title":"Which of the following is NOT a value type in the .NET Framework Common Type System?"
  }
]
```

Here is what a successful working JSON response looks like:

```
{
  "options":[
    {"id":85,"title":"DOS","questionId":22},
    {"id":86,"title":"Altair Basic","questionId":22},
    {"id":87,"title":"PC Basic","questionId":22},
    {"id":88,"title":"Windows","questionId":22}
  ],
  "id":22,
  "title":"What was Microsoft's first product?"
}
```

Maybe this would be helpful:

```
namespace GeekQuiz.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class TriviaQuestion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual List<TriviaOption> Options { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code is the TriviaQuestion model, maybe I'm not treating this correctly. 
If any awesome .NET programmer is looking for a disciple let me know.

Comment: You have a typo in your code,  you have defined `$scope.options` but using `option.`, change it to `options.` like `options.id` etc...

Comment: Tushar, the single option in option.id is a built in angular for each loop, so its just a local variable for the loop i'm declaring to be the object name and then returning the properties with that variable.

Comment: Yeah missed the ng-repeat sorry for that, can you show me the console log, AFAIK, the response returns with data , that is for you it would be data.data.options.. But first to reach into some conclusion i need to c your console log

Answer (score 5):

Because `IEnumerable<T>` is serialized to JSON array.

### About the Angular part...

I guess that `$scope.options = data.options;` is wrong, because you're returning the array itself from the WebAPI, and I can't find a reason to think that your *options* are being serialized in an object which contains a property `options` **but it seems like your data is returned as a JSON array *as is***.

Probably your binding will work if you turn the so-called assignment to `$scope.options = data;`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but that doesn't seem to work. I don't know if its because in TriviaQuestions.cs model class the list from TriviaOptions is coming through. I' really just trying to simplifying the tutorial so that I can understand it from the ground up and build a simple asp.net/angular/restful application.

Comment: @Dlaugh14 How do you want to send multiple trivia questions without using a JSON array?

Comment: Fidemraizer I guess that would be a good question. I guess I initially thought that the list option wasn't there. I'm trying to figure out how to correctly send the questions through an array now, but I was just trying to get a simple example since I haven't worked with arrays too much. Do i need to send it through an array if the <list> TriviaOption is not there?

Comment: @Dlaugh14 well, you can either send an empty list por use `ng-if ` and check if the question has options property